# How do I reset a radio button when I press back on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, reset

I have a webform for which a user can select 3 different types of delete via a radio button.  When then user selects on a different radio button the form changes.  This is [how it looks](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s68/sh/57da4426-d11f-4d90-bc82-bf5aaf812983/31b6a0f1bce324556952782b657f223a).

When I first arrive on this page, the User ID radio and that appropriate form is shown.  However, let's say I decide to search for a contract instead.  Once I arrive to the results page from the delete contract form, if I press back on the browser, I return to my original page, except that the Contract radio button is select while the form for the User ID is shown.  How can I fix this? It is a problem because we don't want to delete a user thinking it is a contract.

I would like that when I press back, either the User radio button and form are selected, or the contract button and form.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/hb6Z7/4/

```
function showhidediv(rad) {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName( rad.name );
  document.getElementById( 'existing_user_section' ).style.display = ( rads[0].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById( 'existing_contract_section' ).style.display = ( rads[1].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById( 'existing_item_section' ).style.display = ( rads[2].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
}

<form name="type_search" class="type_user_class" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 0 0 10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="new_user" value="search_user" checked onclick="showhidediv(this);"/><label>User</label>
  <input type="radio" name="new_user" value="search_contract" onclick="showhidediv(this);"/><label>Contract</label>
  <input type="radio" name="new_user" value="search_item" onclick="showhidediv(this);"/><label class="last">Item</label>
</form>

<section id="existing_user_section">
  form for user
</section>
<section id="existing_contract_section" style="display:none">
  form for contract
</section>
<section id="existing_item_section" style="display:none">
  form for item
</section>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming the browser retains the selection** you can do this

Added values is you can now remove the events from the html

I grab the sectionName from the value - it could be from the ID. Also if needed, you can use cookies to save the state

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AD5Fp/)

```
function showhidediv(rad) {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName(rad.name);
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    var rad = rads[i];  
    var sectionName = rad.value.split("_")[1];  
    document.getElementById( 'existing_'+sectionName+'_section' ).style.display = ( rad.checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }    
}
window.onload=function() {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName("new_user");
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    rads[i].onclick=function() {
      showhidediv(this);
    }
    if (rads[i].checked) {
      rads[i].click();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it did not fix it.  After I search for a contract and then click Back on the browser, the Contract radio button is selected but the User form is still shown. I added you code inside my javascript code at the top of the page, was the correct?

Comment: There is a typo. I am adding to your fiddle

Comment: awesome, that worked! And yeah, no idea why someone downvoted.

Comment: They hopefully voted the partly finished version down I just hope they will return to see this version

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't depend on the accepted solution.

Different browsers handle the back button differently, some allow you to bust the cached page, some do not, some inconsistently between versions.

Most of the time the page is going to be loaded from cache, and the DOM isn't going to initialize all your js files again.   Put an alert at the top of that js and reload the page in a different browser, see if you get alerted again.

I'd recommend looking into the back button cache.  http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/

Comment: Prove that your downvote is valid. For now it is just speculation. I will vote up and/or delete my answer if you can